# Is this e-mail another way to deliver rejection?

Tags: interviewing

I just received this email from the company (after a Skype interview and submitted a few samples of my work), I am not sure if it's nice way to say that I am not getting this job. Here is the email:

> Thank you for sent us your project, we really appreciate it.
>
> We need to talk again at the end of the year, if we have a position
>   available, in order to start to work with new Fall. If you have
>   already plan to come in Europe, please contact us, we can meet in
>   person.
>
> Please, keep in touch.

I actually have a plan to travel to Europe (I am in the US, the company is in the EU) 
next month, but not sure if I can contact and meet them because I don't know if this email contains any possibility of hiring me.

Please give me some advice.

Comment: Did you translate their email, or did they write it like that?

Comment: What is the job position?

Comment: It's a fashion designer position

Comment: They could probably do with hiring a proof reader. If that quote is an actual email that you received, that's atrocious.

Comment: Where is this company based? As comments have said in another answer, it's unusual for Western European countries to use the term Fall. That really is an American/Canadian term. I'd be worried that this isn't a job prospect but a possible scam where people are attempting to get free samples via this project. Keep an eye out for your designs appearing elsewhere!

Comment: Is the company German?

Comment: Note: They offer the possibility to talk at the end of the year *in order to start to work with new Fall*. If they mean starting work next fall, don't wait for them, that's one year from now. If they mean 'working on the Fall fashion collection' that would mean a much earlier start date.

Comment: @gnasher729 That depends on who contacted whom here. A lot of companies wouldn't even bother communicating in English for something like this.

Answer (score 7):

Is this a rejection? Yep, sounds like it. But! Not a total rejection. Try not to interpret too much, but take advantage of exactly what the message says:

> "We need to talk again at the end of the year"

This is a permission for you to reach out to them again before end of this year (say, in early-mid December) with an inquiry regarding any openings at that time.

The part that is unclear to me is why the work would start so late, in "new Fall" (Fall 2017)? It might be a good question to ask them about the typical duration between recruitment and start date.

> If you have already plan to come in Europe, please contact us.

This statement provides justification for you to contact them to let them know exactly when you plan to be in Europe. Say that you would appreciate the opportunity to meet in person to talk more about your qualifications, and ask about their availability during the dates when you will be there.

Also, "Europe" seems fairly broad - make sure you are willing (and can afford) to travel to their actual location before you actually offer to meet. It will not make you look good if you arrange a meeting and then cancel on them after realizing that logistics are not convenient for you.

Finally, realize that there may be multiple reasons for the tentative "rejection." It may have nothing to do with your qualifications, but a change in the internal situation of the employer, such as budget issues, or sudden cancellation of recruitment for this position. These things happen, and new opportunities can emerge just as quickly as existing opportunities disappear. I encourage you to follow up with them based on the suggestions above, and see how it goes. Good luck!

Comment: "Is this a rejection? Yep, sounds like it. But! Not a total rejection."  - Yes, in other words, it could mean "not now" instead of "no"

Comment: Or it could mean you are not in Europe and we are looking for someone local enough to start soon with out having to relocate or get work visas.  But we may have more time on a position later in the year.

Answer (score 3):

You were probably a candidate for the position but unfortunately not the top candidate.

In the Fall probably means after they know what positions are open.

Definitely follow up.

Comment: It seems strange for an English-speaking European to use the term "Fall" to refer to the season. "Autumn" would normally be used in my experience. But then the whole message seems a little strange - as though it's been through google-translate, so who knows ...

Comment: @brhans English doesn't appear to be their native language, so they probably learnt "International English" (i.e. American)

Comment: Both native and non-native English speakers are quite capable of producing something as bad as this. For any European, using "fall" instead of "autumn" would be very unusual.

Comment: I am not saying Fall means autumn.  It is used as "term" or "cycle" in a poorly worded document.   English may not have been a first language for the writer.

Comment: In US English, "Fall" can be a direct idiomatic synonym for autumn. In my dialect, there is absolutely nothing surprising about the decision to use the less formal word.

Comment: Maybe as they were emailing someone based in the US they thought to use the term they felt the recipient would be most familiar with.